# Could not find FPGA device on the board for connection 'Local': Ultra96-Board Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xilinx, zynq, soc

I am following the "Developing Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC Hardware Technical Training Course" on [Hackster.io](https://Hackster.io/) for a basic `Hello World` program on my Ultra96 board.

Once I was at Lab2's end, I was supposed to launch my `Hello World` program on the Zynq MPSoC. However, I got this warning:

```
Program FPGA failed

Reason:
Could not find FPGA device on the board for connection 'Local'.

Troubleshooting hints:
1. Check whether board is connected to system properly.
1. In case of zynq board, check whether Digilent/Xilinx cable switch settings are correct.
1. If you are using Xilinx Platform Cable USB, ensure that status LED is green.**
```

I am working on Ubuntu and am using the SDK 2018.3. Also I use the [AES-ACC-U96-JTAG board](https://www.avnet.com/shop/us/products/avnet-engineering-services/aes-acc-u96-jtag-3074457345635355958/) to interface via MicroUSB. So a how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You must build kernel with fpga manager support. The easiest way to get a working system is to start with a PYNQ2.6 distribution for Ultra96, it's got all the right settings already.

Comment: Looks like a lot of FPGA-related questions are downvoted / closed here (always by people with only web crap in their tags)... That's stackoverflow for you. As for using Pynq - it's just the regular Ubuntu 18.04 with a couple of additions and a right kernel, so tutorial will most definitely work with it. Otherwise you'll have a lot of fun building Petalinux for Ultra96.

Comment: P.S., ok, I see, you're not running Ubuntu on MPSoC, so it's not an fpga manager in kernel issue... There's a lot of tutorials, so hard to figure out which one you're referring to.  I assume you're using Vitis and connecting to the board using usb jtag board. It's supposed to work (my setup - Vitis 2019.1 + Ubuntu 18.04, everything works fine). Can you provide a more precise error message and `lsusb` output with the board connected? Also, check your usb cable.

Comment: Oh alright, thank you. Yeah I already solved the issue. The drivers havent been installed automatically by the Vivado/Vitis setup, so they had to be installed manually. Pynq seems to be a nice solution, however I am currently not able to use it because of the tutorials and my companies constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xilinx Unified Installer does not install the USB drivers required to recognize an FPGA board on a Linux system. As such, it must be done manually after the tools have been installed.

Please refer to the following links. I solved my problem by manually installing the xilinx cable dirvers.

1. https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/guides/install-cable-drivers
2. https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug344.pdf
3. https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/59128?language=en_US

Go to the location:

`<Vivado Install>/data/xicom/cable_drivers/lin64/install_script/install_drivers/`

`sudo ./install_drivers`

`sudo adduser $USER dialout`

Comment: This did the trick for us with Vivado 2022.2 in Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you!!!

Comment: BTW, "which vivado" points to the install location; there was no symlink

Answer (score 1):

I was searching around the web and found [this post](https://community.element14.com/products/devtools/avnetboardscommunity/avnetboard-forums/f/general/38702/zedboard-xilinx-sdk-program-fpga-failed-usb-jtag).

Since I am on Ubuntu, I went to the standard installation path for my Vivado/SDK.
It should look a bit like this:

`/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/`

There, I found a "cable drivers" directory:

`../data/xicom/cable_drivers/lin64/install_script/install_drivers`

The content of this directory should be:

```
52-xilinx-digilent-usb.rules
52-xilinx-ftdi-usb.rules
52-xilinx-pcusb.rules
install_digilent.sh
install_drivers
setup_pcusb
setup_xilinx_ftdi
```

I unplugged all my cables (the AES-ACC-U96-JTAG board) and ran this script: `install_drivers`.

Now I restarted the SDK, replugged my cable and tried the programming of the FPGA again, and it worked.
So the solution was to just reinstall/update the drivers which are usually installed via Vivado.

I hope this helps some folks.

---

Short hint: The setup document for the VirtualBox of Xilinx actually mentions this.